# Who was Nicodemus talking about near the end of Skin Game?

Tags: the-dresden-files

When talking with

> Deirdre,

Nicodemus assures this character that his plan will keep them "safe from the Enemy". Was he referring to God, Nicodemus's traditional chief enemy, or was he talking about

> Nemesis?

We know the latter has been rolling in circles that Nicodemus and Co. frequent, and could make his statement actually not misleading.

> It seemed like he was promising Deirdre that she'd avoid God's Judgement by leaving her to face Hades's. Could he have instead been putting her in one of the few places that we can be nearly sure the Outsiders can't reach? The Underworld is used as a mixed high security prison and armory against the Outsiders, it's got to be as safe from Nemesis as one can be, except at peer locations like Arctis Tor, Demonreach, etc.

Edit: there are other people that this character and Nick both hate, but they're unlikely to get a capital E in Enemy.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that he was referring to one of the traditional Enemies (though it isn't clear to me whether he meant God or Lucifer).

There's no evidence that those who die have to worry about their souls being taken/destroyed/tormented by outsiders or

> Nemesis.

There *is*, however, a lot of references to people being concerned about their immortal souls as they relate to Heaven or Hell.

It is therefore likely that Nick was referring to Satan/Lucifer.  He has previously been referenced as 'The Enemy' in The Dresden Files, albeit by people opposed to the Nickelheads.  It's entirely likely that Nick and the other people who have taken up with the Fallen Angels of the Denarii will still consider an eternity of torment at the hands of Lucifer as their likely fate, and their goals do not necessarily align with Lucifer's.  Therefore, he would still be considered their Enemy.

With the situation they find themselves in, with

> Diedre's soul virtually certain to be stuck in Hades realm instead of being released to its natural destination

she *is* going to be protected from Lucifer.

> Unfortunately, she didn't read her Greek mythology.  I expect she'd prefer a lake of fire over whatever Hades will do to her for eternity.  Lucifer uses pretty much equal-opportunity torment.  Hades gets *creative*.

Comment: Ah, I meant the possibility that the character in question knew their Greek Mythology, but was worried about being taken over by N. Certainly, we know that Nicodemus has recently experienced unusual dissension in his ranks (as much as the Nickleheads could ever have ranks). Could it be possible that the character in question was actively fighting off N? That would make a sacrifice with neat symmetry to the one when Harry first met the Knights.

Comment: @rsegal: I doubt it.  *N* would anticipate the power of the artifacts being brought to bear against it's side and would not have been such a crucial aid in attaining it.  So far as I can tell, no one can resist *N* to anything near the degree you imply.  Lea, most powerful Sidhe of the Winter Court (excluding the Queens) couldn't effectively resist N to that degree even with the **direct** support of Mab.  The best she could do is sputter a disjointed warning to Harry.

Comment: I believe the message Michael delivers while channeling the power of Uriel about not avoiding judgement is actually direct support of this answer, although I don't have my copy handy to verify.

Comment: @Jeff You might be right, but I don't think that those are good pieces of evidence: if Harry can resist the temptation of L, it's possible that this character could have resisted N. Other characters show resistance to N even after they'd been compromised. Plus, we don't know how long it takes N whispering in someone's ear to corrupt them.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. from the books I believe, that the Enemy are Outsiders. As in all of them, albeit most of the stories are currently revolving about a single covert operative, that is N, who hijacks anything he can: Fae, mortals, the Fallen... And the way he spreads is uncertain, but is obviously similar to some kind of a virus or parasite.

> I believe that is one of the reasons why Nicodemus is cooperating with Lasciel
>  [ or vice versa ] and offered the coin to Dresden. It is fairly difficult to 
>  determine who is taken by N and who not. But Dresden as a Starborn has probably some kind of resistance against being infected.

Also...

> This development somewhat points to what might be the theme of Peace Talks:
>  Either peace talks between current groups vs the Fomor OR peace talks between all groups vs the Outsiders. 
>  Though the latter would be a steep escalation at this point, but I expect it to come later on.